# Is anyone used react-native-background-geolocation?

Tags: react-native, geolocation, location, background-process

I am using the example code given on the `react-native-background-geolocation` library home page:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Switch,
    Text,
    View,
 } from 'react-native';

 import BackgroundGeolocation, {
    Location,
    Subscription
 } from "react-native-background-geolocation";

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    subscriptions:Subscription[] = [];
    state:any = {};
   constructor(props:any) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       enabled: false,
       location: ''
     }
 }

componentDidMount() {
 /// 1.  Subscribe to BackgroundGeolocation events.
this.subscriptions.push(BackgroundGeolocation.onLocation((location) => {
  console.log('[onLocation]', location);
  this.setState({location: JSON.stringify(location, null, 2)})
}, (error) => {
  console.log('[onLocation] ERROR:', error);
}))

this.subscriptions.push(BackgroundGeolocation.onMotionChange((event) => {
   console.log('[onMotionChange]', event);
 }))

this.subscriptions.push(BackgroundGeolocation.onActivityChange((event) => {
  console.log('[onActivityChange]', event);
}))

this.subscriptions.push(BackgroundGeolocation.onProviderChange((event) => {
  console.log('[onProviderChange]', event);
}))

/// 2. ready the plugin.
BackgroundGeolocation.ready({
  // Geolocation Config
  desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.DESIRED_ACCURACY_HIGH,
  distanceFilter: 10,
  // Activity Recognition
  stopTimeout: 5,
  // Application config
  debug: true, // <-- enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
  logLevel: BackgroundGeolocation.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE,
  stopOnTerminate: false,   // <-- Allow the background-service to continue tracking when user closes the app.
  startOnBoot: true,        // <-- Auto start tracking when device is powered-up.
  // HTTP / SQLite config
  url: 'http://yourserver.com/locations',
  batchSync: false,       // <-- [Default: false] Set true to sync locations to server in a single HTTP request.
  autoSync: true,         // <-- [Default: true] Set true to sync each location to server as it arrives.
  headers: {              // <-- Optional HTTP headers
    "X-FOO": "bar"
  },
  params: {               // <-- Optional HTTP params
    "auth_token": "maybe_your_server_authenticates_via_token_YES?"
  }
}).then((state) => {
  this.setState({enabled: state.enabled});
  console.log("- BackgroundGeolocation is configured and ready: ", state.enabled);
 })
}

/// When view is destroyed (or refreshed during development live-reload),
 /// remove BackgroundGeolocation event subscriptions.
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => subscription.remove());
}

onToggleEnabled(value:boolean) {
   console.log('[onToggleEnabled]', value);
   this.setState({enabled: value})
   if (value) {
    BackgroundGeolocation.start();
    } else {
    this.setState({location: ''});
     BackgroundGeolocation.stop();
    }
  }

 render() {
   return (
      <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text>Click to enable BackgroundGeolocation</Text>
        <Switch value={this.state.enabled} onValueChange={this.onToggleEnabled.bind(this)} />
       <Text style={{fontFamily:'monospace', fontSize:12}}>{this.state.location} </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
}
```

But I am facing the issue, when I start tracking initially it gives 2 response like below:

```
{
"coords": {
    "ellipsoidal_altitude": 0,
    "speed_accuracy": 0,
    "longitude": -122.02994396,
    "speed": 3.56,
    "floor": 0,
    "heading_accuracy": 0,
    "latitude": 37.33067786,
    "accuracy": 10,
    "heading": 90.76,
    "altitude": 0,
    "altitude_accuracy": -1
},
"extras": {},
"is_moving": false,
"event": "motionchange",
"odometer": 7897.8,
"age": 776,
"uuid": "0B7B6369-4C31-45C8-ADC3-2A85DFBF3040",
"battery": {
    "level": -1,
    "is_charging": false
},
"activity": {
    "type": "unknown",
    "confidence": 100
},
"timestamp": "2024-02-29T05:00:02.372Z"
}
```

Then for a few seconds, I got no response for location change even though my location is continuously changing.

Does anyone have any idea about how can I get continuous responses from the start?